# unable to use Users.messages: modify google API option

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-api-dotnet-client

Can some one help me out with the below exception ?
Here is the .Net code I am using to move Inbox message to another label

```
{
List<String> labelsToAdd = new List<string>();
labelsToAdd.Add("Label_1");
//List<String>`enter code here` labelsToRemove = new List<string>();
//labelsToRemove.Add("INBOX");

ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
mods.AddLabelIds = labelsToAdd;
//mods.RemoveLabelIds = labelsToRemove;

gmail.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, usr, email.Id).Execute();
}
```

and I am getting the error like this

> GoogleAPIException - {"An Error occurred, but the error response could
>   not be deserialized"}
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException - {"Unexpected character
>   encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."}
>
> StackTrace -    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
>
> at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type
>   objectType)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type
>   type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>
> at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input) in
>   C:\Apiary\v1.21\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Json\NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.cs:line
>   148
>
> at
>   Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.d__34.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Apiary\v1.21\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis\Apis\Services\BaseClientService.cs:line 288

Comment: Please supply a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve the code you have posted works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have works fine for me the only issue I think you may be having is that `labelsToAdd.Add("Label_1");`  may not be a label id.  However when I try and send an invalid label Id I am getting

> Invalid label: adfadsfdsf [400]

This is the code I used.

Auth

```
/// <summary>
/// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
/// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
/// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
/// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
/// <returns>DriveService used to make requests against the Drive API</returns>
public static GmailService AuthenticateOauthGmail(string clientSecretJson, string userName)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecretJson))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecretJson");
        if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
            throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

        // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
        string[] scopes = new string[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsSharing,   //Manage your sensitive mail settings, including who can manage your mail
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsBasic,     //Manage your basic mail settings                                 
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,          //View your emails messages and settings
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose,           //Manage drafts and send emails
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailInsert,            //Insert mail into your mailbox
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels,            //Manage mailbox labels
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailModify,            //View and modify but not delete your email
                                         GmailService.Scope.GmailSend,              //Send email on your behalf
                                         GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom};                             //View and manage your mail
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

            // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                     scopes,
                                                                     userName,
                                                                     CancellationToken.None,
                                                                     new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Gmail Oauth2 Authentication Sample"
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create Oauth2 account GmailService failed" + ex.Message);
        throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountGmailFailed", ex);
    }
}
```

The request.

```
// find the label I want to use.
var findLabel = serviceGmail.Users.Labels.List("me").Execute().Labels.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower().Equals("daimto")).FirstOrDefault();

// search for the mails that I want to add it to
var request = serviceGmail.Users.Messages.List("me");
request.Q = "from:stuff@daimto.com";
request.Execute();

var allmails = request.Execute();           

ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
mods.AddLabelIds = new List<string> { allLabels.Id };

// loop though each email.
foreach (var item in allmails.Messages)
   {
   var result = serviceGmail.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, "me", item.Id).Execute();
   }
```

I am using 1.19.0.694 of the Gmail.dll  the code is coming from my sample project [Google-dotnet-samples gmail v1](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0/Gmail%20API/v1)

Comment: Thanks for responding.. but when tried with your code i am getting the same issue... so do you think is there any scope issue

Comment: credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
                        (
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                         new[] { "https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify" },
                        usr,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, fullpath)
                        ).Result;

Comment: You probably don't need all those scopes I was just testing but you can see how they should be formed with the library.

Comment: everything is working as expected apart from this line of code .... 
var result = serviceGmail.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, "me", item.Id).Execute();

Comment: I am not getting the exact error here that's the problem

Comment: you called it right?   var serviceGmail = AuthenticateOauthGmail(jsonOauth2File, "User");

Comment: Yes I am, but in other way 
 var gmail= new GmailService();
                // Create Gmail API service.
                gmail = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                       HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                       ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                 });

Comment: is there any way to check the exact exception .... apart from this message "An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized"

Comment: Just make sure you check your scopes the ones you posted wont work you should be forming them like I have.

Comment: even i tried changing scopes as you did.. but no luck. can I have your email id? so that i will share my complete code to you..

Comment: done posted in your site.. please check and revert me

Comment: Much easer with your full source code you should edit your question and put what you sent me in there.

Comment: Have the same problem.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: This is whats returned in the exception 
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid id value [400]
Errors [
 Message[Invalid id value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalidArgument] Domain[global]
]